# Jquery dialog and Ajax trouble

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi everyone and first of all thanks for everything, well here is the question:

each time a hit the submit button that I have linked with the jquery trying to make an AJAX request to open a dialog in modal mode the jquery dosen't execute, I must have done something wrong but can't seem to find it, here is the code:

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" charset="utf-8">
<head>      
    <title>Administrador :: Estructuras M&amp;M ::</title>
    <link href="../CSS/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="../CSS/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="login">
            <form method="post" id="ingreso" name="ingreso">
                <div><label class="etiqueta">Usuario:</label><input type="text"      maxlength="15" id="usuario" name="usuario" /></div>
                <div><label class="etiqueta">Clave:</label><input type="password" maxlength="15" id="clave" name="clave" /></div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Aceptar" id="verificar" /></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and this is the Jquery im trying to execute:

```
 $('#verificar').click(function()
        {
            var xmlhttp;

                try
                {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch(e)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        catch(e)
                        {
                            alert("Su navegador no soporta AJAX, por favor pruebe con otro.");
                            return false;
                        }                        
                    }
                }
                if(xmlhttp)
                {
                    var dialog = $("<div id='modal' class='cargando' title='Verificando Usuario por favor espere.'><span>Verificando la existencia del usuario por favor espere.</span></div>").appendTo('body');

                    dialog.dialog(
                    {
                        height: auto,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close");} },
                        draggable: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        close: function(event, ui) 
                        {
                            dialog.remove();
                        }
                    });
                }            
        });
```

I really wish to make it work right so I'm open to all type of suggestions, thanks.

Oh and after I open the modal I'm supposed to send the ajax info to a PHP page to verify if the user exists, just haven't done it cause I was testing it out first,

Comment: try $('#verificar').click(function() ... etc

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input.verificar')
```

is a selector that is looking for inputs with a *class* of 'verificar'. what you want is to find an object with the *id* of 'verificar'.

```
$('#verificar')
```

Comment: Hi friend, I changed the jquery to check for the id, but it is still producing the same effect, it just verifies if it was clicked but it doesn't do anything afterwards.